# AngularJS ng-if inside ng-repeat but only for that iteration

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.8.2 and can't upgrade.

I have a loop like so:

```
<div class="cart-items" ng-repeat="item in cart.Items track by $index">
    <div>
        <div class="cart-item-quantity">
            <input keep-focus type="number" min="1" ng-min="1"  
                ng-model="cart.Items[$index].Quantity" max="{{cart.Items[$index].MaxQuantity}}"
                ng-max="cart.Items[$index].MaxQuantity"
                ng-change="update(cart.Items[$index].SKUID, cart.Items[$index].Quantity, false)" 
                ng-blur="update(cart.Items[$index].SKUID, cart.Items[$index].Quantity, true)" 
                ng-disabled="cart.Items[$index].MaxQuantity == 1" 
                id="CartItem[{{$index}}]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item-detais">
            {{cart.Items[$index].Name}}<br/>
            <span class="price" ng-bind-html="cart.Items[$index].UnitPriceTotalFormatted | trustHtml"></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="CartForm.$invalid" class="red"> <------- THIS --------->
          error message here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to cover the edge case where the input max attribute is overriden by the keyboard but this shows the error message under each cart item.
Is there something like `ng-if="CartForm.#CartItem[{{$index}}].$invalid"` and only have it show up in that iteration?

I know this can be done in javascript if needs be but would rather keep it angular if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your input fields with their index; something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="someInput_{{$index}}" />
<div ng-if="(Form['someInput_{{$index}}'].$touched || Form.$submitted) && Form['someInput_{{$index}}'].$invalid">
    <span ng-if="Form['someInput_{{$index}}'].$error.max">Some input exceeded max value!</span>
</div>
```